# Why $\mathbb E_2[T]=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb E_1[T]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb E_3[T]+1$?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)$ a Markov chain on $\mathbb Z$ s.t. $$\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=i+1\mid X_n=i)=\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=i-1\mid X_n=i)=\frac{1}{2},$$
for all $n$. We denote $\mathbb P_i$ the probability measure when $X_0=i$, and $\mathbb E_i$ the expectation w.r.t. the measure $\mathbb P_i$. Let $T$ being the first time when $(X_n)$ is in $\{1,4\}$.

Suppose that Let $h_i=\mathbb P_i(T<\infty )$ and $k_i=\mathbb E_i[T]$. For me it's clear from the fact that $$\mathbb P(X_n=j\mid X_1=i)=\mathbb P_i(X_{n-1}=j),$$
and the Markov property that we have that $$h_2=\frac{1}{2}h_1+\frac{1}{2}h_3.$$

However, I don't understand why $$k_2=\frac{1}{2}k_1+\frac{1}{2}k_3+{\color{red}{1}},$$

Where does the $+1$ comes from ? In my lecture it's written : "the $+1$ appear because we count the time for the first step", but I don't really understand the argument. Any explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose at time $0$ you were in state $1$ or $3$ with equal probability. Then the expectation of the first time when reach your target is $\mathbb P(X_0=1)\mathbb E_1(T)+\mathbb P(X_0=3)\mathbb E_3(T)=\frac12\mathbb E_1(T)+\frac12\mathbb E_3(T)$.

But that's not the case - you were in state $2$ at time $0$, so you are in state $1$ or $3$ with equal probability at time $1$. Since the chain is time-homogeneous, this just means everything happens $1$ time step later than the case above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm trying to understand, but I really don't get the point. Next time I can either be in ($2$ or in $0$) or in ($2$ and $4$)... this +1 still puzzled me.

Comment: @joshua the time to get from (either 1 or 3) to (target) is $\frac12E_1(T)+\frac12E_3(T)$. But the time to get from 2 to (either 1 or 3) is $1$. So the time to get from 2 to (target) is $1+\frac12E_1(T)+\frac12E_3(T)$.

Comment: got it, thank you.

Comment: I recently asked essentially the same question, and a few days later, I found the a formal proof. You can check it out here: [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4847465/182437)